# How to prove that a vector field with holes in its domain is conservative without finding a potential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have to prove that $$\vec{F}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r^2}$$ is a conservative vector field **without** finding it's potential function.

However, $\vec{F}$ has a hole in its domain, at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, so I can't just check it's curl.

How do I go about proving this?

Answer (score 4):

For this example it still suffices to show that $\operatorname{curl} \vec F = 0$. It's true that the domain of $\vec F$ has a hole, but the domain is still simply connected: Any loop in the domain, say, based at a point can be continuously deformed to the constant path that sits at that point.

Alternatively, in spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \varphi)$, the gradient is $$\operatorname{grad} f = f_r \vec r + \frac{1}{r} f_{\theta} \vec \theta + \frac{1}{r \sin 
\theta} f_{\varphi} \vec \varphi.$$ In particular, the gradient of a radial function $f(r)$ is $$\operatorname{grad} (f(r)) = f_r(r) \vec r ,$$ so the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus guarantees that *any* continuous radial vector field (not defined at the origin, where spherical coordinates behave badly) is conservative.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would explain their objection?

Comment: The second part is beyond me, but for domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ where I can visualize a closed curve. Is it true that domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ are simply connect iff there is no hole going all the way through the domain? And finally, if the curl is 0 and the domain is not simply connected, can I just pick any closed curve $\gamma$ which I can visualize as being deformable into any and all other closed curves, and check to see if the circulation is $0$? I don't know how to prove mathematically that $\gamma$ is deformable into any other $\gamma$, but if it

Comment: is visually easy to tell that a single $\gamma$ can be stretched/morphed into all other possible closed curves, then checking our single $\gamma$ suffices?

Comment: It's hard to give precise answers more of the language of topology available. In any case: The plane $\Bbb R^2$ is different from higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces in the sense that removing a single point gives a space $\Bbb R^2 - \{\ast\}$ that is not simply connected. A loop that goes around $\ast$ once, for example, cannot be continuously deformed into a constant loop. (But this is not true for $\Bbb R^n$, $n \geq 3$.) "No hole going all the way through the domain" is a good way to think informally about the condition on holes in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: In the example, it's not that we can pick a loop $\gamma$ that is deformable into all other loops (this is only possible when the space is simply connected in the first place), but rather that we can pick a loop $\gamma$ such that for every curve $\alpha$, there is some integer $n$ such that $n \gamma$---the curve that wraps around gamma $n$ times---is deformable into $\alpha$.

Comment: If we can find such a curve $\gamma$, then like you say, it suffices to check whether the circulation along $\gamma$ is zero, but for some more complicated domains there will be no such curve gamma---instead, we'd need to pick curves $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_k$ such that any curve $\alpha$ can be deformed into some curve $\gamma_{a_1}^{b_1} \cdots \gamma_{a_r}^{b_r}$ for some indices $a_1, \ldots, a_k$ and integers $b_i$ and then check the circulation of the vector field over each $\gamma_i$. In general it is not easy to determine visually whether a single curve $\gamma$ suffices.

Comment: If we have a donut domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$, this domain is not simply-connected right? I can imagine a closed curve inside the donut that can be deformed into an other closed curve. So in this case with the curl $0$, checking a single closed curve is enough because I can "visualize" that any closed curve is deformable into any other? This was my thinking in my first 2 comments, but this way of thinking seems to not be correct according to your replies. I must be misunderstanding your comments and answer

Comment: No wait, nevermind. I don't think my donut thought process works. Not every closed curve can be made by deforming a single closed curve